# Things in Mr Lee's apartment

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Talking about Faridah's side mission in New Hengsha:

So I hacked the computer, spent 10 minutes searching for the second item (the clock) and Jensen still thinks there's more.  What am I looking for and where is it? I've wasted more time than I care to admit looking for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The four things you have to find are:

1. His voicemail, on the phone next to his bed
2. His emails (not sure if there is a way besides hacking to obtain this)
3. The baseball bat in the corner to the right of the door
4. The clock on the mantle, the murder weapon

Comment: And yes, this part took me forever to find, I eventually had to back to to a save game and do computer->phone->bat->clock. I think sometimes it doesn't even highlight the bat or the clock until you go through the other two first.

Comment: I actually never had the clock highlighted - the fact that it was broken caught my eye.  Even with that I spent a good ten minutes looking around that place.

Comment: Being forced to find them in order is the somewhat-annoying catch for this mission: you do a thorough sweep of the apartment and find only one actionable thing, then as you're leaving you hear there's more to find in what you're sure is a clean apartment. I could understand this as a plot point if each thing you find has a reason to make you notice the next thing, but the things are relatively independent.

Comment: Use an automatic unlock device if you don't want to hack the email.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least a baseball bat in the kitchen which Jensen thinks might also be used as a weapon, because it was cleaned recently.